# How can I dynamically display all products of a specific collection?

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

How can I dynamically display the selected collection in the customizer?
My code so far is

```
{% for collection in collections %}
    {% for product in collection.products %}
      {% if product.featured_image %}
        <img src="{{ product | img_url }}">
      {% endif %}
      <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
      <p>{{ product.price | money }}</p>
    {% else %}
      <p>There is no product in {{ collection.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

But it display all collections that I have in my store. What do I need to do in order to display the selected collection?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be specific at this point.

```
{% for collection in collections %}
```

That is ALL your collections. Instead, cherry-pick the one you want.

```
{% for collection in collections['my-pink-pony'] %}
```

And like magic, your code is dealing with the collection you want.

Comment: Thank you for this but this is not what I am looking for. I have a schema and in the customizer in shopify when I choose this specific collection I want it to be display.

Comment: Your question said nothing about schemas nor customizers, so I guess you're stuck trying to articulate your real problem.

Comment: if you choose a collection into customiser, you can use the like this to get collection data.

Comment: ```{% for collection in collections[section.settings.schemaidforyourcollection] %}```

Comment: Theme Customizer is a work in progress. Best questions about how to use it be directed at Shopify.